# Grails not using DataSource.groovy file for test environment

Tags: grails

I want to change data base from inbuild H2 to Mysql database in grails , Grails documentation says change in Datasource.groovy file will change the database but it is working only for my development environment but not for test environment , Even i have tried removing the complete Datasource.groovy file and deleted the database from mysql and try to run the test it just succeeds ,so can any body help what is the mistake i am doing .

I have went almost all the question in stackoverflow every body suggesting to change in DataSource.groovy file but it doesn't work for me .

```
dataSource {
pooled = true
driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
username = "root"
logSql =true
password = "root"

properties {
    maxActive = -1
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 1800000
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 1800000
    numTestsPerEvictionRun = 3
    testOnBorrow = true
    testWhileIdle = true
    connectionProperties = "[autoReconnectForPools=true]"
    testOnReturn = true
    validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
}
}

hibernate {
cache.use_second_level_cache = true
cache.use_query_cache = true
cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}

environments {
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
        url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/devenvi"
    }
}
test {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
        url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/testenvi"
    }
}
production {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/prodenvi"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you post your DataSource.groovy file?

Answer (score 2):

1) Make sure you have a section in DataSource.groovy for your test environment, example:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
}
environments {
    test {
        dataSource {
            url = "jdbc:mysql://liveip.com/liveDb"
            // other environment-specific settings here
        }
    }
}
```

2) make sure you are doing a build that specifies the **test** environment:

```
/path/to/grails -Dgrails.env=test war
```

will generate project.war file that will use the appropriate environment setting in your DataSource.groovy file

Comment: Hey i posted my DataSource.groovy . I am using eclipse to run the test case

Comment: Are you specifying the test environment? As in 'grails test run-app'

Comment: you can press Command+Option+Shigt+G to get the grails menu in STS and run that command there (on a Mac, anyway)

Comment: Ya i am running in test environment only , even at the top of the STS console it shows the command as "test -app  -integration" which is running

Comment: Hrm... could you post your integration test?